# Issue inserting multiple rows using PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is the form in which I am using to try and create multiple rows to insert into a database.

```
  <input name="input[]" type="checkbox" value="0" id="input_0" /> Directional<br /> <br/>
  <input name="input[]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="input_1" /> Technical <br />
  <br />
  <input name="input[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="input_2" /> Reference <br />
  <br />
  <input name="input[]" type="checkbox" value="3" id="input_3" /> Research <br />
  <br />
  <input name="input[]" type="checkbox" value="4" id="input_4" /> Phone <br /></h3>

  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit Tally" style="height: 25px; width: 100px">
  </Form>
```

Current issue of inserting multiple rows into mysql database from a checkbox form using implode. Would a loop work to fix this issue? I can see the array (#,#,#,#) when check boxes are selected

```
  $type = $_POST['input'];
 // $sid = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $user = $_POST['user'];

  if(count($type) > 0)
  {
  $type_string = implode(',', $type);

  }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tally (tid, sid, uid, date, time, catid) 
      VALUE (NULL, 1, '$user', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$type_string')";


        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
     echo "Success";

     print_r($type_string);
```

Comment: SQL Injection? That's an affirmative, captain.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having?

Comment: Would a loop work to fix this issue? Yes, it should.

Answer (score 0):

A loop would certainly work, after you created some array from that $type variable you receive as input, and feed this into your query one at the time.

But I hope you're not going to use this code in some website just like this. As maiotano84 already commented, the way you create your query is a little dangerous. It is very easy to do some unwanted things with your data. At least you should put your variables through a function like

```
string mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

Here is some more info on this function frm the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) site.

Answer (score 0):

compute the value of `$type` as below:

```
  $i=0;
  foreach ($_POST as $v) {
   if(isset($v['input'.$i])) {
    $type = $v; 
    $i++;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Form action="" method="POST">

  <input name="input[]" type="checkbox" value="0" id="input_0" /> Directional<br /> <br/>
  <input name="input[]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="input_1" /> Technical <br />
  <br />
  <input name="input[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="input_2" /> Reference <br />
  <br />
  <input name="input[]" type="checkbox" value="3" id="input_3" /> Research <br />
  <br />
  <input name="input[]" type="checkbox" value="4" id="input_4" /> Phone <br /></h3>

  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit Tally" style="height: 25px; width: 100px">

  </Form>

  <?php
  $type = $_POST['input'];
 // $sid = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $user = $_POST['user'];

  for($i=0;$i<count($type);$i++){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tally (tid, sid, uid, date, time, catid) 
      VALUE (NULL, 1, '$user', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ".$type[$i].")";  
  }
  ?>
```